# If A and B are both invertible, then $[(A^{-1})B]^T$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, transpose

> If $A$ and $B$ are both invertible, then $[A^{-1}B]^T$ is invertible.

Is this true or false? I have tried coming up with a proof but I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Try $[B^{-1}A]^T$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ and $B$ are both invertible, $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$, then the inverse of $(AB)^t$ is $(B^{-1}A^{-1})^t=(A^{-1})^t(B^{-1})^t$ since

\begin{align}
(AB)^t\cdot (B^{-1}A^{-1})^t&=(B^tA^t)\cdot((A^{-1})^t(B^{-1})^t)\\
&=B^t(A^t\cdot (A^{-1})^t)(B^{-1})^t\\
&=B^t(A^{-1}A)^t(B^{-1})^t\\
&=B^t I^t (B^{-1})^t\\
&=B^t I (B^{-1})^t\\
&=B^t \cdot (B^{-1})^t\\
&=(B^{-1}B)^t\\
&=I^t\\
&=I
\end{align}
Now for your question amend the above with $A$ replaced by $A^{-1}$. Also note a matrix $A$ is invertible iff its determinant, $\det(A)\neq0$, and then $\det(A^{-1})=(\det(A))^{-1}$. Plus $\det(A)=\det(A^t)$ and $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

$A, B, AB$ are invertable if their respective determinants don't equal 0.

Now what ruled do you know about determinants, products, inverses and transposes.

i.e. $det(AB) = det(A)det(B)$ and 
$(A^{-1} B)^T = B^T(A^{-1})^T$

etc.

You should have enough to show that $det (A^{-1} B)^T \ne 0$

Comment: invertible if determinant equals 0 ?

Comment: @anderstood thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The product of invertible matrices is invertible; the transpose of an invertible matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Assume $\ds{C \equiv\pars{A^{-1}B}^{T}}$ is $\color{#f00}{not}$ invertible. It means $\ds{\det\pars{C} = 0}$ Then, you'll arrive to a contradiction because

\begin{align}
AC^{T} & = B\quad\implies\quad\det\pars{A}\det\pars{C} = \det\pars{B} = 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Multiply by $[B^{-1}A]^T$, remembering that $[XY]^T=Y^TX^T$.